# Mapping a column to a Map hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Is there a native way of mapping a single column to a Map in hibernate besides writing a customer UserType ?

The column needs to contain key , value properties. Probably it is better to have a separate table in this case but I am interested in having it in a single Column.

Comment: JPA allows you to define an `AttributeConverter`, so you could convert the map to a String or something. Tried that? That way you use no JPA provider specific nonsense The provider I use documents this http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_map_converter_simple_simple

Comment: @BillyFrost thanks for the hint

Comment: A map has key/value pairs.  What value is a single column?  Don't you need two values for each entry in a map?

Comment: You can easily put a map as string. like .    key=value separator key=valie separator and so on....

Comment: What's the problem with the user type?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger . No problem I was just hoping Hibernate has some sort of built in mechanism to storemaps in some form. F.ex. JSon.... or something else.

Answer (score 1):

JPA allows you to define an `AttributeConverter`, so you could convert the map to a String or something. Tried that? That way you use no JPA provider specific nonsense, and hence your code is portable.

The provider I use documents this [here](http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_map_converter_simple_simple).